# UWP: How to perform action in a BackgroundTask

Tags: javascript, jquery, winapi, uwp

I am building a UWP App in JavasScipt.  
The Documentations I am following:

[Create and register an out-of-process background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task)
[Support your app with background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks)

Here is the BackgroundTask initialization:

```
(function () {
    "use strict"

    // Initialization
    var Background = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;

    // Register
    var taskBuilder = new Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder();
    taskBuilder.name = "MyBackgroundTask";

    // init trigger
    var appTrigger = new Background.ApplicationTrigger();
    taskBuilder.taskEntryPoint = "clipboardListener.MyBackgroundTask";
    taskBuilder.setTrigger(appTrigger);

    // Check if background task already registered
    var taskRegistered = false;
    var iter = Background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.allTasks.first();
    var hascur=iter.hasCurrent;
    while (hascur)
    {
        var current = iter.current.value;
        if (current.name == "MyBackgroundTask")
        {
            taskRegistered = true;
            break;
        }
        iter.moveNext();
    }

    if (!taskRegistered)
    {
        var task = taskBuilder.register();
    }
})();
```

Here is how I setup the task:

```
function runBackgroundTask() {
    appTrigger.requestAsync().then(function (result) {
        closeRun();
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

As you can see, I set the `appTrigger` variable in the code above to set the trigger for the task.

1. What would I need to trigger the background task whenever the user copies something to his clipboard?
2. How can I perform something whenever the background task runs?

Comment: hey jonhue, can u help me how to create background task using timer using js only ,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.What would I need to trigger the background task whenever the user copies something to his clipboard?

Listening for clipboard changes in background task is not supported. We can find all supported triggers under [Windows.ApplicationModel.Background Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background) and there is no such trigger in UWP.

> 2.How can I perform something whenever the background task runs?

This will depend on how you implement your background task. Usually, we would create a **Windows Runtime Component** and in the component, write classes that implement the [**IBackgroundTask**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.IBackgroundTask) interface.

Using the C# Windows Runtime Component for example, a basic background task class would like the following:

```
namespace Tasks
{
    public sealed class ExampleBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {

        }        
    }
}
```

And the [**Run**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.IBackgroundTask#methods_) method is where we used to perform what we want. This method is a required entry point that will be called when the specified event is triggered.

For more info, please see **[Create the Background Task class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task#create-the-background-task-class)** in [Create and register an out-of-process background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task#create-the-background-task-class).